# CodeIgniter URL routes not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

Usually CodeIgniter URL format is `domain/controllerName/functionName/:id` but I want it like `domain/product-name/product-detail-page`. I have made changes in `routes.php` also but it gives me `404 page`.

Comment: Have you look here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Also check your class and file name make sure only first letter is upper case. example: `Welcome.php` and `class Welcome extends CI_Controller {}`

Comment: I was refering this link only and tried this $route['index/viewAllCourses'] = 'coursess'; in my routes.php file but when i load my domain/index/viewAllCourses page it gives me 404 page. Classes names are all fine.

Comment: you need dynamic routing from database ? or static route?

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar dynamic. i dont want controller name or method name, i just want the product name to display like this domain/product-name

Comment: wait , i will make an answer that contain create dynamic route in codeigniter , and i think , you need that ;)

Comment: @shubhamsaini I am not sure why your using upper case though for your routes.php you also do `$route['index/viewAllCourses'] = 'coursess'; ` try some thing like `$route['viewallcourses'] = 'coursess/index';`

Comment: Alert: Some one is serial down voting on here.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 why serial down ?? what's wrong with my question ?? How to stop it ??

Comment: I don't know it just looked like some one had downvoted a lot. That why put alert. but it has been a while now any way.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Why the downvote ?

Comment: @shubhamsaini Was not me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
application/config/routes.php

$route['product-detail/(:any)'] = 'Controller/function/$1';
```

on browser you hit `product-detail/<product id>` this will call `Controller/function/$1` here $1 will represents the product id

```
public function product_detail($product_id)
```

Refer to codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: i tried the way you suggested. $route['index/(:any)'] = 'index'; where index is my controller name. So when i hit any URL with index/blah-blah it should redirect me to index/ page but nothing is happening.

Comment: ok, set routes like this `$route['product-detail/(:any)'] = 'index/product_detail/$1'`, create a function in your index controller like this `public function product_detail($product_id)` . Hopes this will help you.